# I need force delete service in AKS cluster, my namespace is deleted but the svc is alive

Tags: kubectl, azure-aks

I need force to delete service in my AKS cluster
i try `kubectl delete svc`
the service is alive.

i try `kubectl delete svc`
.
.
I try deleting the namespace
.
.
I try recreating the namespace
my namespace is deleted but the svc is alive

Answer (score 0):

To force delete service in AKS, check this out-

First see what all deployments running using

```yaml
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

***output***

[image]

Either you can delete the whole deployment altogether using

```yaml
$ kubectl delete deployment <NAME>
```

In this case it will be `vault`

Next way is, list the service you want to delete along with any particular namespace you deployed it in using `kubectl get svc -n <namespace> -o wide`

***output***
[image]

Now let's force delete this `vault-ui` svc

`kubectl delete svc <svc-name> -n <namespace_name> --grace-period=0 --force`

***output***
[image]
,
`vault-ui` service is not available anymore

***output***
[image]

Reference document:

[K8s Doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/)

[How to Force Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336665/how-do-i-force-delete-kubernetes-pods)

[Delete svc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47693911/how-to-delete-kubernetes-service)